# MA model is always giving same output in time series(python)

Tags: python, time-series, prediction, arima

Does MA model can be used for prediction? In **time series** analysis, my ARIMA order is (0,1,7),which indicates that it is a MA model, unfortunately I am always getting a **straight** line for my prediction. Only first 7 values are different, as the lag is 7 here. And after that **it predicts the same value.**

my question is " **is it normal that the model is predicting like that** or there is a solution to overcome this problem. I would be grateful if anyone could help.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, for a simple MA model it's normal to have a straight line for the prediction. Simple AR and MA models are intended to perform one-step-ahead predictions. In your case, you have a `MA` order of `7`, so after your first seven "step ahead" the predictions start to repeat since you don't have new data.

One way to avoid this would be to treat the predictions as ground-truth values and retrain the model with them. But don't expect this to improve your results significantly.

For a more detailed explanation, I suggest reading this section from the [Forecast: Principles And Practices](https://otexts.com/fpp3/arima-forecasting.html) by Hyndman.

Comment: So then any Arima model cannot predict longer than the value we get in q of (p,d,q)?, what if I wanted to predict the next 30 days, I would need to choose another model?